How to Create a Responsive Grid with Unequal Heights and Different Order on Mobile?
I'm using Tailwind CSS to create a responsive grid layout where sections have different orders on mobile and desktop. The sections also have different heights based on their content. The mobile layout is working fine, but on desktop, I can't get section 3 to fill the empty space and expand upwards properly.
Mobile Layout:

Sections should be in this order: 1 → 2 → 4 → 3.

Current Code
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-2 auto-rows-auto">
  <div class="bg-gray-300 h-16 sm:col-span-2 order-1">1</div>
  <div class="bg-teal-300 h-64 sm:col-span-2 sm:order-3 order-4">3</div>
  <div class="bg-red-200 h-32 sm:col-span-1 sm:order-1 order-2">2</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-200 h-32 sm:col-span-1 sm:order-4 order-3">4</div>
</div>

Output - Desktop

Issue
Section 3 should fill the remaining height on the left but doesn’t go up correctly.
Expected layout
Section 3 should rise up and fill the space beneath section 1, while sections 2 and 4 remain stacked on the right.


This happens because the children elements are fixed height. I suggest you to use min-height, then the elements will fill all space on grid. You can see the code below or on tailwind playground.
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-2">
  <div class="bg-gray-300 min-h-16 sm:col-span-2 order-1">1</div>
  <div class="bg-teal-300 h-64 sm:col-span-2 sm:order-3 order-4">3</div>
  <div class="bg-red-200 h-32 sm:col-span-1 sm:order-1 order-2">2</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-200 h-32 sm:col-span-1 sm:order-4 order-3">4</div>
</div>

